# Remove all before and after Number X Number

Tags: regex, numbers, expression, character, ranorex

I ask my first question here because I need to isolate some characters in

```
Fri  2 Mar 2012  11:14:25
JPEG **960x640** 960x640+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64.7KB 0.016u 0:00.017
```

I want isolate `960X640` but this variable can change every time :(
And the result I got is on many line like the example.

So I need a regex to delete all before 960X640 and all after.

Thank you so much if you try to help me :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `\d+x\d+` will match any **numberxnumber**

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @ASGM Since the OP wants to replace, we need the language he's using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should match the target:

```
[0-9]+x[0-9]+
```

So this should work to remove everything else:

```
Search: .*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.*
Replace (perl etc): \1 
Replace (java): $1
```

Comment: Ok Same result for thanks you but it don't work but if i use find operation with [0-9]+x[0-9] i obtain "960x6" It's better than nothing :) How can i specify for obtain 960x640 ?

Comment: Ok [0-9]+x[0-9]+ work great if you search in Fri 2 Mar 2012 11:14:25

JPEG 960x640 960x640+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64.7KB 0.016u 0:00.017 for finding

960x640

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This must solve your problem:

```
/\d+x\d+/
```

Comment: The possessive quantifier might not be supported. Usually, normal greedy quantifier is good enough.

Comment: @nhahtdh: pehraps, but the language is not specified! The used language can not support the \d class or don't need separators in this way!

Comment: There are languages which supports the `\d` but does not support `++`, only plain `+` is supported, such as JS, Python `re`.

Comment: @stevefigueras : what language or tool Do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sed would use syntax like:

`s/^[^0-9]+[[:space:]]([0-9]+x[0-9]+)[[:space:]].*$/\1/`

Perl would look like:

`s/^\D+\s([0-9]+x[0-9]+)\s.*$/$1/`

For example:

```
$ echo 'JPEG 960x640 960x640+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64.7KB 0.016u 0:00.017' | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]+[[:space:]]([0-9]+x[0-9]+)[[:space:]].*$/\1/'
960x640
```

Comment: Ok thanks you but it don't work but if i use find operation with [0-9]+x[0-9] i obtain "960x6"
It's better than nothing :) 

How can i specify for obtain 960x640 ?

Comment: @stevefigueras you left off the + on the second character class.  It should read [0-9]+x[0-9]+